# get the value undefine on onkeyup when used setTimeout function

Tags: javascript

i have call function on onkeyup event of textbox which pass the data using ajax.below is sample code of my function which in .js file.

```
var timeout;
function testfont(id,image) 
{
    alert('image');//when alert here it shows value
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout( function()
    {
        if(image.match(/_small/g))
        {
            var image = image.replace('_small','');
        } else {
            var image = image;
        }
        alert('image'); //when alert here it show undefined
    }, 500);
}
```

But the problem is that i get the image value undefined inside setTimeout function.it works perfectly without use of setTimeout but i need setTimeout function for event fire after some time.

how can i resolve this?

Comment: Don't use tabs to indent posted code, use spaces. Better formatting should make it more obvious where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making variables in each of your condition.

```
function testfont(id,image) 
{
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout( function() {
    if(image.match(/_small/g)){
    image = image.replace('_small','');
    }
    else{
        image = image;
    }
    alert(image);//when alert here it show undefined
}, 500);
}
```